# Image with live updating text

Tags: image, updates, live, automatic-updates

Need some help with images.

As the topic says, I want to create an image with live updating text on it.
This is mainly used by game servers and players to show off their stats and info. Server-wise, to show if the server is online and how many players are online and such.

I haven no idea how to do it and figured this would be the best place to find out. Since I don't have any idea what this is even called, i did not know what to search for.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Are you displaying this on a web page? Need more context.

Comment: Yes, this will be displayed on a website. All information will be loaded to a database which I will connect to so there will always be a constant connection between a site and the database. It will mainly work as a Forum Signature.

Answer (score 0):

This is an html+css+ajax solution. Make the image an html element's background image. Let's use a div. Then position the text in the div. Use ajax to update the text. The image will remain the same while the text can be updated.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use the image on many site, so I will have to use a fixed link to the image. Will this still work? I mean, since im linking to the image, the ajax and css wont go with it. Thought about `iframe` but cant be used in signatures.

Comment: You cannot use css+ajax unless you can link to them as well. How are you creating the image? Are you using a server side programming language?

Answer (score 0):

Was possible with the use of API. Created an API of the database I want to use, connected to the database and everything worked!
After using `$API_GET` to get the data, I set it into an array-format.

**Used PHP for everything.**

From there on I used `imagecreatefrompng`, obviously to select an image.
Set a few colors using `imagecolorallocate` and from there on it was purely adding the text on the image as to where I want them using `imagettftext`.

Creating an image, with live updating stats on it.

But we still have to tell the browser to load it as an image and not a page with an image on it, so therefor...

`header( "Content-type: image/png" );`

And `imagesetthickness` to 5, followed by `imagepng` and `imagedestroy`.

Code Extracts:

```
$API_GET = file_get_contents("API URL");
$API_GET = json_decode($API_GET);
$API = array();

foreach ($API_GET as $key => $value) {
    $API[$key] = $value;
}
if (file_exists($imagefile)) {
    $bg_img = imagecreatefrompng ( "IMAGE URL");
    $color_red = imagecolorallocate( $bg_img, 250, 0, 0 );
    imagettftext($bg_img, 20, 0, 19, 36, $color_red, 'FONT URL.tff',"Text On Image");
    imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );    
    header( "Content-type: image/png" );
    imagepng( $my_img );
    imagedestroy( $my_img );
} else {
    echo 'Image does not exist.';
}
```

That is the basic structure of the code. 
Thank You for your reply to the question.